# CrudRepository Query update is inserting a new row , rather than updating an existing one

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to update a row in a table, but it creates a new row, rather than update an existing one.
I created the following table

```
create table if not exists credential (
credential_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
system_id varchar(50),
domain varchar(50),
custom_key varchar(50),
user_name varchar(50),
credential varchar(500),
PRIMARY KEY (credential_id)
);
```

I have the following entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="credential")
public class CredentialEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long credentialId;
    String systemId;
    String domain;
    String customKey;
    String userName;
    String credential;
    
    public CredentialEntity() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CredentialEntity(String systemId, String domain, String customKey, String userName,
            String credential) {
        super();
        this.systemId = systemId;
        this.domain = domain;
        this.customKey = customKey;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.credential = credential;
    }

    public String getSystemId() {
        return systemId;
    }

    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

    public String getCustomKey() {
        return customKey;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getCredential() {
        return credential;
    }
}
```

And I have the following update statement

```
@Modifying
    @Query("update CredentialEntity c set c.credential= ?1 where c.systemId = ?2 and c.domain = ?3 and c.customKey = ?4 and c.userName = ?5")
    public void updateCredential(String credential, String systemId, String domain, String customKey, String userName);
```

what it does is insert another row into the table

from

```
mysql> select * from credential;
+---------------+-----------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
| credential_id | system_id | domain | custom_key | user_name | credential                              |
+---------------+-----------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
|             8 | AAAA      | BBBB   | CCCC       | user1     | {"userName":"user1","password":"pass1"} |
|             9 | AAAA      | BBBB   | CCCC       | user2     | {"userName":"user2","password":"pass2"} |
```

After running update I get

```
+---------------+-----------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
| credential_id | system_id | domain | custom_key | user_name | credential                              |
+---------------+-----------+--------+------------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
|             8 | AAAA      | BBBB   | CCCC       | user1     | {"userName":"user1","password":"pass1"} |
|             9 | AAAA      | BBBB   | CCCC       | user2     | {"userName":"user2","password":"pass2"} |
|            10 | AAAA      | BBBB   | CCCC       | user2     | {"userName":"user3","password":"pass3"} |
```

What I wanted was two rows the second one user2, updated to user3 and password3

Comment: Do you have a limitation that didn't use the Spring JPA repository method `Save()`? Just pass the primary key and it handles the update operation. Anyway, what did you find when you debug? Is it distinguished that this record already has been in DB?

Comment: I did not use the primaryKey, its not used anywhere, its just autogenerated. I want to be able to update on those fields.
I those 4 fields are used to identify a single item in the database. So if I update a row, its identified by those 4 fields.

Comment: If you can only update by the primary key, that is a weakness with JPA, then I will have to rethink my schema Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The above code does work. A very silly mistake.
I was calling the wrong method, instead of calling the service that called the update, it was calling the set method.

Dont code at night when you misplace your glasses.